# Migrating xDB data to cloud

Tags: xdb, cloud

We have our xDB setup on one of our server and we are now migrating to xDB cloud. We have just taken xDB cloud subscription.

Can you please suggest the tool to migrate the content?

Comment: Rajesh, please consider accepting an answer that helped you the most, as this will indicate to the future readers that you've found a solution to your problem. There is no obligation to do this, but this is a good practice in the format of our community.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a list of services that xDB Cloud officially provides:

[**xDB Cloud - Service Catalog and Policies**](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/042722)

As you can see, there's nothing about importing data to the cloud. Only an export option:

> **xDB Set export** | Customers can obtain an export/backup of their collectionsDB data

Having personally spoken with xDB Cloud technicians, I understand that they *may* in some cases restore your MongoDB backup for you, but that is not something they normally do. So you'll need to contact your [**regional sales department**](http://www.sitecore.net/company/contact-us) and/or [**Sitecore Support**](https://support.sitecore.net/helpdesk/) to see if this will be possible.

Note that if you have any xDB-related customizations in your solution, they will not be supported in xDB cloud. This concerns custom segments, facets, etc. that you may have been using on premise.

Answer (score 2):

xDB On-Premise migration to xDB Cloud is officially available as part of the service catalog, so can be simply requested from Sitecore Support:
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/042722.

Look for "xDB Set Data Import" item.
Also, check more details at https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/861225.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any Sitecore specific tools that will help migrating to the cloud. Instead, look at MongoDb migration "tools". The easiest would be to do a backup/restore similar to SQL.

```
mongodump --db newdb --out /var/backups/mongobackups/`date +"%m-%d-%y"`

mongorestore --db newdb --drop /var/backups/mongobackups/12-11-16/newdb/
```

I would reach out to Sitecore to see whether they can execute the restore for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore won't take your mongodump from on-premises and restore them on top of MonogoDB instance that is a part of Sitecore xDB Cloud hosting offering. However, you can directly connect to databases in MongoDB. Which means, technically you can move all data from the `analytics`, `tracking.contact` etc. databases from your MongoDB on-premises to MongoDB in the cloud. Then you must run [History Processing](https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/81/xdb_cloud/customizing/rest_api_reference_for_the_xdb_cloud_service#_Trigger_history_processing) operation to rebuild the `reporting` database in SQL Server.

Comment: Do MongoDB accounts provided by xDB Cloud have the [**required securtity permissions**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#required-access) to be able to restore data?